# Use MassTransit for Azure Service Bus with a 'send' shared access policy

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm starting a project and plan to use MassTransit to send a message to an Azure Service Bus queue. On the queue itself, I'd like to have a Shared Access Policy that only has 'Send' permission.

I've configured MassTransit in my Startup as it shows in the documentation and used the connection string from the "Send" access policy. When I try to send the message, it appears to complete successfully, but the message never shows up in the queue. The only way I've been able to get it to work is to add 'Manage' permissions to the shared access policy, which also gives 'Listen' permissions to the same policy.

Is there some undocumented configuration where I can use a SAS policy that doesn't have 'Manage' permissions?

Comment: MassTransit needs to have the Manage permission because it has to configure topics and subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I'll give that a try. The project I'm working on will not be using topics, so I will try to configure as suggested in that post.

Comment: Using Topics is one of the main benefits of using MassTransit.  All that configuration of which consumer is listening to which queue is handled automatically.  TBH I would reconsider using MT if you aren't using it's main features